# Resolver erro de sintax ao apertar enter no teclado sem digitar nada

Tags: python, syntax-error

Boa noite galera.
Meu primeiro post, sou inciante e pode parecer uma pergunta boba mas está me tirando o sono.
Agradeço a ajuda.
No código abaixo, ao apertar o enter sem digitar nada no imput é retornado um erro e ja tentei de tudo mas ainda não consegui resolver e acabo não conseguindo seguir com os estudos.
Tem alguma forma de resolver ou é algo normal?

```
cont = ('Zero', 'Um', 'Dois', 'Treis', 'Quatro', 'Cinco', 'Seis', 'Sete', 'Oito', 'Nove', 'Dez',
        'Onze', 'Doze', 'Treze', 'Quatorze', 'Quinze', 'Desesseis', 'Desessete', 'Dezoito', 'Dezenove', 'Vinte')

for c in range(0, 20):
    num = int(input('Digite um número entre 0 e 20: ')).
    if 0 <= num <= 20:
        print(f'Você digitou o número {cont[num]}')
        next = str(input('Deseja continuar? [S/N] ')).upper().strip()[0]
        if next == 'N':
            break
    else:
        print('Valor inválido! Tente novamente.')
print('Fim do Programa')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode tratar a exceção com `try/except`:

```
while True:
  try:
    num = int(input('Digite um número entre 0 e 20: '))
    break
  except ValueError:
    print("Digite somente números!")
```

Com isso enquanto o valor digitado não for um número, o sistema solicitará novamente o usuário a digitar um valor.

> Veja online: https://repl.it/@Dadinel/BusyFrailActiveserverpages

---

Também é possível verificar o valor presente em `num` antes de converter com a função `int`, usando por exemplo o método `isdigit`:

```
num = ""

while not num.isdigit():
  num = input('Digite um número entre 0 e 20: ')

num = int(num)
```

A ideia é a mesma, enquanto o valor não for um número, o usuário fica dentro do `while`, solicitando assim um novo valor.

> Veja online: https://repl.it/@Dadinel/LavenderTemptingFirm

---

Apenas uma observação, a função `input` já retorna um `str`, portanto não é necessário converter, então nesse trecho:

```
next = str(input('Deseja continuar? [S/N] ')).upper().strip()[0]
```

Você pode remover a função `str`, pois já terá esse retorno:

```
next = input('Deseja continuar? [S/N] ').upper().strip()[0]
```

---

> Documentações:
>
> https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html
>
> https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html
>
> https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input

Comment: Daniel Mendes, agradeço muito suas respostas.
Vou implementar e dormir hoje rsrs.